# How to get payload values from byte[] message in Spring Integration int-http:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, http, integration, spring-el, payload

I am configuring an `outbound-gateway` in my context.xml where I want to extract values from a `byte[]` type payload and use them to construct a `URI`. I found that SpEL allows you to build it this way:

```
url-expression="T(org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)
                       .fromHttpUrl('http://HOST:PORT/PATH')
                       .queryParams(payload)
                       .build()
                       .toUri()"
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#mapping-uri-variables

My variation of the solution looks like this:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="candleRequestGateway"
                           request-channel="candleRequestChannel"
                           reply-channel="dataResponseChannel"
                           http-method="GET"
                           url-expression="T(org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)
                                        .fromHttpUrl('some/{path}')
                                        .queryParam('myParam', payload.get('myParam'))
                                        .buildAndExpand(payload.get('path'))
                                        .toUri()"/>
```

However, I am getting the following error which occurs while executing `payload.get('myParam')` part:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#3]; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method get(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type byte[]
```

I understand and agree with the error. My question: is there a way (a specific SpEL expression(?)) to extract the values from `byte[]` payload without having to transform it before it reaches the `outbound-gateway`? Is this a valid solution at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what are you expecting `payload.get('myParam')` and `payload.get('path')` to do when the payload is a `byte[]`.

Clearly, a `byte[]` does not have a `get(String)` method.

> to extract the values from `byte[]`

Extract how? A `byte[]` is an unstructured array of bytes; the only thing you can do is something like `new String(payload).substring(0, 5)` or similar.

If the bytes contain JSON, you could use a `#jsonPath` SpEL function.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell. Yes, the payload is a JSON. The solution you're proposing is most likely the correct one. I was able to achieve the goal by putting a `json-to-object-transformer` before the gateway. Not ideal but works. I am having an issue with `#jsonPath` though. I have `json-path-2.4.0.jar` in my classpath but it still complaining with `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1006E: Function 'jsonPath' could not be found`. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can run in a debugger, set a breakpoint in `DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.registerBuiltInBeans()` which is where the SpEL function is registered (if the class is found on the CP).